# Why did I get a bunch of items from just logging in?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I logged into TF2 for the first time in about 6 months today and received almost 15 items, mostly genuine, upon arrival. I was under the impression that you needed to spend time in game in order to earn items. I'm not complaining, but why did I get them and how (if possible) can I replicate this?

PS: I can provide a list of the items I got when I get home in a few hours.

Comment: Probably bonus items for buying other stuff on steam?

Comment: I don't think so, I've never gotten items from buying steam games before so I can't imagine it would start now.

Comment: @slow_excellence They're tied to specific games.  For instance, pre-ordering Alien: Resurrection will net you 5 items.

Comment: What items did you get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Genuine quality](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Genuine) items are obtained *only* as promotional items from purchasing other Steam games. Most likely you purchased a few games during that time and didn't realize there was a promotional item involved.

Comment: If OP bought a load of games during steam summer sale, he got his source. Tho usually larger or more known titles grant items like this. Such as if you own saints row 3 (or 4) you can get "the penetrator" (a massive dildo...) as your sword in Shadow Warrior.

Comment: It's been years since I bought a load of games during the summer sale lol. But this is interesting to know.